# python lines that start with @

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Python decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

I was reading a django app source code where I find this

```
@login_required
def activities(request = None,\
            project_id = 0,\
            task_id = 0,\
            ...
```

What does the line that start with @ mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Comment: +1 because it is a valid question, because you don't know, that you have to search for decorators when you see the `@` symbol the first time.

Comment: Also the right duplicate would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out [Python Decorators Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators). It has an amazing answer that will explain everything.

Answer (score 5):

It's a decorator. What it does is basically wrap the function. It is equivalent with this code:

```
def activities(request = None,\
            project_id = 0,\
            task_id = 0,\
            ...
activities = login_required(activities)
```

It is used for checking function arguments (in this case `request.session`), modifying arguments (it may give the function other arguments than it passes), and maybe some other stuff.

Answer (score 4):

It's a decorator, which is a special type of function (or class, in some cases) in Python that modifies another function's behavior. See [this article](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/).

```
@decorator
def my_func():
    pass
```

is really just a special syntax for

```
def my_func():
    pass
my_func = decorator(my_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a decorator. It's a syntatic sugar for:

```
def activities(request = None,\
            project_id = 0,\
            task_id = 0,\
            ...

activities = login_required(activities)
```