# Cosine Similarity between 2 Number Lists

Tags: python, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate the **cosine similarity** between **two lists**, let's say for example list 1 which is `dataSetI` and list 2 which is `dataSetII`.

Let's say `dataSetI` is `[3, 45, 7, 2]` and `dataSetII` is `[2, 54, 13, 15]`. The length of the lists are *always* equal. I want to report cosine similarity as a number between 0 and 1.

```py
dataSetI = [3, 45, 7, 2]
dataSetII = [2, 54, 13, 15]

def cosine_similarity(list1, list2):
  # How to?
  pass

print(cosine_similarity(dataSetI, dataSetII))
```

Answer (score 321):

Another version based on `numpy` only

```
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm

cos_sim = dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))
```

Comment: FYI this solution is significantly faster on my system than using `scipy.spatial.distance.cosine`.

Comment: Even shorter: `cos_sim = (a @ b.T) / (norm(a)*norm(b))`

Comment: On my system, SciPy is roughly the same speed as this, for tiny/dummy use-cases. SciPy is optimised for efficiently comparing large lists of vectors. For large lists of vectors, SciPy is orders of magnitude faster

Comment: Worth noting that this is `1 - scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(a, b)`

Answer (score 272):

You should try [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/getting_started.html). It has a bunch of useful scientific routines for example, "routines for computing integrals numerically, solving differential equations, optimization, and sparse matrices." It uses the superfast optimized NumPy for its number crunching. See [here](http://www.scipy.org/install.html) for installing.

Note that spatial.distance.cosine computes the **distance**, and not the similarity. So, you must subtract the value from 1 to get the **similarity**.

```
from scipy import spatial

dataSetI = [3, 45, 7, 2]
dataSetII = [2, 54, 13, 15]
result = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(dataSetI, dataSetII)
```

Answer (score 119):

You can use `cosine_similarity` function form `sklearn.metrics.pairwise` [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html)

```
In [23]: from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

In [24]: cosine_similarity([[1, 0, -1]], [[-1,-1, 0]])
Out[24]: array([[-0.5]])
```

Answer (score 54):

I don't suppose performance matters much here, but I can't resist.  The zip() function completely recopies both vectors (more of a matrix transpose, actually) just to get the data in "Pythonic" order.  It would be interesting to time the nuts-and-bolts implementation:

```
import math
def cosine_similarity(v1,v2):
    "compute cosine similarity of v1 to v2: (v1 dot v2)/{||v1||*||v2||)"
    sumxx, sumxy, sumyy = 0, 0, 0
    for i in range(len(v1)):
        x = v1[i]; y = v2[i]
        sumxx += x*x
        sumyy += y*y
        sumxy += x*y
    return sumxy/math.sqrt(sumxx*sumyy)

v1,v2 = [3, 45, 7, 2], [2, 54, 13, 15]
print(v1, v2, cosine_similarity(v1,v2))

Output: [3, 45, 7, 2] [2, 54, 13, 15] 0.972284251712
```

That goes through the C-like noise of extracting elements one-at-a-time, but does no bulk array copying and gets everything important done in a single for loop, and uses a single square root.

ETA: Updated print call to be a function. (The original was Python 2.7, not 3.3.  The current runs under Python 2.7 with a `from __future__ import print_function` statement.) The output is the same, either way.

CPYthon 2.7.3 on 3.0GHz Core 2 Duo:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("cosine_similarity(v1,v2)",setup="from __main__ import cosine_similarity, v1, v2")
2.4261788514654654
>>> timeit.timeit("cosine_measure(v1,v2)",setup="from __main__ import cosine_measure, v1, v2")
8.794677709375264
```

So, the unpythonic way is about 3.6 times faster in this case.

Answer (score 29):

without using any imports

> math.sqrt(x)

can be replaced with

> x** .5

without using numpy.dot() you have to create your own dot function using list comprehension:

```
def dot(A,B): 
    return (sum(a*b for a,b in zip(A,B)))
```

and then its just a simple matter of applying the cosine similarity formula:

```
def cosine_similarity(a,b):
    return dot(a,b) / ( (dot(a,a) **.5) * (dot(b,b) ** .5) )
```

Answer (score 17):

I did a [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/mckelvin/5bfad28ceb3a484dfd2a) based on several answers in the question and the following snippet is believed to be the best choice:

```
def dot_product2(v1, v2):
    return sum(map(operator.mul, v1, v2))


def vector_cos5(v1, v2):
    prod = dot_product2(v1, v2)
    len1 = math.sqrt(dot_product2(v1, v1))
    len2 = math.sqrt(dot_product2(v2, v2))
    return prod / (len1 * len2)
```

The result makes me surprised that the implementation based on `scipy` is not the fastest one. I profiled and find that cosine in scipy takes a lot of time to cast a vector from python list to numpy array.

[image]

Comment: Please advise on the tool you are using to get visualized representation of time consumed per line of code.

Comment: @YoungSheldon It has been too long. Probably https://github.com/uber-archive/pyflame

Answer (score 17):

Python code to calculate:

- Cosine Distance
- Cosine Similarity
- Angular Distance
- Angular Similarity

---

```
import math

from scipy import spatial


def calculate_cosine_distance(a, b):
    cosine_distance = float(spatial.distance.cosine(a, b))
    return cosine_distance


def calculate_cosine_similarity(a, b):
    cosine_similarity = 1 - calculate_cosine_distance(a, b)
    return cosine_similarity


def calculate_angular_distance(a, b):
    cosine_similarity = calculate_cosine_similarity(a, b)
    angular_distance = math.acos(cosine_similarity) / math.pi
    return angular_distance


def calculate_angular_similarity(a, b):
    angular_similarity = 1 - calculate_angular_distance(a, b)
    return angular_similarity
```

---

**Similarity Search**:

If you want to find closest cosine similarity in array of embeddings, you can use `Tensorflow`, like the following code.

In my testing, closeset value to an embedding with the shape of 1x512 found in 1M embeddings (1'000'000 x 512) in less than a second (using `GPU`).

```
import time

import numpy as np  # np.__version__ == '1.23.5'
import tensorflow as tf  # tf.__version__ == '2.11.0'

EMBEDDINGS_LENGTH = 512
NUMBER_OF_EMBEDDINGS = 1000 * 1000


def calculate_cosine_similarities(x, embeddings):
    cosine_similarities = -1 * tf.keras.losses.cosine_similarity(x, embeddings)
    return cosine_similarities.numpy()


def find_closest_embeddings(x, embeddings, top_k=1):
    cosine_similarities = calculate_cosine_similarities(x, embeddings)
    values, indices = tf.math.top_k(cosine_similarities, k=top_k)
    return values.numpy(), indices.numpy()


def main():
    # x shape: (512)
    # Embeddings shape: (1000000, 512)
    x = np.random.rand(EMBEDDINGS_LENGTH).astype(np.float32)
    embeddings = np.random.rand(NUMBER_OF_EMBEDDINGS, EMBEDDINGS_LENGTH).astype(np.float32)

    print('Embeddings shape: ', embeddings.shape)

    n = 100
    sum_duration = 0
    for i in range(n):
        start = time.time()
        best_values, best_indices = find_closest_embeddings(x, embeddings, top_k=1)
        end = time.time()

        duration = end - start
        sum_duration += duration

        print('Duration (seconds): {}, Best value: {}, Best index: {}'.format(duration, best_values[0], best_indices[0]))

    # Average duration (seconds): 1.707 for Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10700 CPU @ 2.90GHz
    # Average duration (seconds): 0.961 for NVIDIA 1080 ti
    print('Average duration (seconds): ', sum_duration / n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For more advanced similarity search, you can use [Milvus](https://milvus.io/), [Weaviate](https://weaviate.io/) or [Faiss](https://faiss.ai/).

---

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity
- https://gist.github.com/amir-saniyan/e102de09b01c4ed1632e3d1a1a1cbf64

Answer (score 11):

```
import math
from itertools import izip

def dot_product(v1, v2):
    return sum(map(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], izip(v1, v2)))

def cosine_measure(v1, v2):
    prod = dot_product(v1, v2)
    len1 = math.sqrt(dot_product(v1, v1))
    len2 = math.sqrt(dot_product(v2, v2))
    return prod / (len1 * len2)
```

You can round it after computing:

```
cosine = format(round(cosine_measure(v1, v2), 3))
```

If you want it really short, you can use this one-liner:

```
from math import sqrt
from itertools import izip

def cosine_measure(v1, v2):
    return (lambda (x, y, z): x / sqrt(y * z))(reduce(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0] * y[1], x[1] + y[0]**2, x[2] + y[1]**2), izip(v1, v2), (0, 0, 0)))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this simple function to calculate the cosine similarity:

```
def cosine_similarity(a, b):
  return sum([i*j for i,j in zip(a, b)])/(math.sqrt(sum([i*i for i in a]))* math.sqrt(sum([i*i for i in b])))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in Python using simple function:

```
def get_cosine(text1, text2):
  vec1 = text1
  vec2 = text2
  intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
  numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])
  sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
  sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
  denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)
  if not denominator:
     return 0.0
  else:
     return round(float(numerator) / denominator, 3)
dataSet1 = [3, 45, 7, 2]
dataSet2 = [2, 54, 13, 15]
get_cosine(dataSet1, dataSet2)
```

Comment: This is a text implementation of cosine. It will give the wrong output for numerical input.

Comment: Can you explain why you used set in the line "intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())".

Comment: Also your function seems to be expecting maps but you are sending it lists of integers.

Answer (score 3):

Using numpy compare one list of numbers to multiple lists(matrix):

```
def cosine_similarity(vector,matrix):
   return ( np.sum(vector*matrix,axis=1) / ( np.sqrt(np.sum(matrix**2,axis=1)) * np.sqrt(np.sum(vector**2)) ) )[::-1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another version, if you have a scenario where you have list of vectors and a query vector and you want to compute the cosine similarity of query vector with all the vectors in the list, you can do it in one go in the below fashion:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> A      # list of vectors, shape -> m x n
array([[ 3, 45,  7,  2],
       [ 1, 23,  3,  4]])

>>> B      # query vector, shape -> 1 x n
array([ 2, 54, 13, 15])

>>> similarity_scores = A.dot(B)/ (np.linalg.norm(A, axis=1) * np.linalg.norm(B))

>>> similarity_scores
array([0.97228425, 0.99026919])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) already, you should go with their [CosineSimilarity implementation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.CosineSimilarity).

Suppose you have two `n`-dimensional `numpy.ndarray`s, `v1` and `v2`, i.e. their shapes are both `(n,)`. Here's how you get their cosine similarity:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

cos = nn.CosineSimilarity()
cos(torch.tensor([v1]), torch.tensor([v2])).item()
```

Or suppose you have two `numpy.ndarray`s `w1` and `w2`, whose shapes are both `(m, n)`. The following gets you a list of cosine similarities, each being the cosine similarity between a row in `w1` and the corresponding row in `w2`:

```
cos(torch.tensor(w1), torch.tensor(w2)).tolist()
```

Comment: I suggest using the functional implementation of the cosine similarity directly (torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity), instead of instantiating the module implementation and applying the instance of your tensor.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **SciPy** (easiest way):

```py
from scipy import spatial

dataSetI = [3, 45, 7, 2]
dataSetII = [2, 54, 13, 15]
print(1 - spatial.distance.cosine(dataSetI, dataSetII))
```

Note that `spatial.distance.cosine()` gives you a dissimilarity (distance) value, and thus to get the similarity, you need to subtract that value from 1.

Another way to get to the solution is to write the function **yourself** that even contemplates the possibility of lists with different lengths:

```py
def cosineSimilarity(v1, v2):
  scalarProduct = moduloV1 = moduloV2 = 0

  if len(v1) > len(v2):
    v2.extend(0 for _ in range(len(v1) - len(v2)))
  else:
    v2.extend(0 for _ in range(len(v2) - len(v1)))

  for i in range(len(v1)):
    scalarProduct += v1[i] * v2[i]
    moduloV1 += v1[i] * v1[i]
    moduloV2 += v2[i] * v2[i]

  return round(scalarProduct/(math.sqrt(moduloV1) * math.sqrt(moduloV2)), 3)

dataSetI = [3, 45, 7, 2]
dataSetII = [2, 54, 13, 15]
print(cosineSimilarity(dataSetI, dataSetII))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can easily calculate cosine similarity with simple mathematics equations.
Cosine_similarity = 1- (dotproduct of vectors/(product of norm of the vectors)). We can define two functions each for calculations of dot product and norm.

```
def dprod(a,b):
    sum=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        sum+=a[i]*b[i]
    return sum

def norm(a):

    norm=0
    for i in range(len(a)):
    norm+=a[i]**2
    return norm**0.5

    cosine_a_b = 1-(dprod(a,b)/(norm(a)*norm(b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be the most efficient way to find cosine similarities between two matrixes of numbers - no for/loops, all in numpy.

```
def cos_sim(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray):
    
    out_dim = 2        
    if len(b.shape) == 1:
        b = b.reshape([1,-1])
        out_dim -=1
    if len(a.shape) == 1:
        a = a.reshape([1,-1])
        out_dim -=1
        
    norm1 = norm(a.astype(float), axis=1, keepdims=True)
    norm2 = norm(b.astype(float), axis=1, keepdims=True)
    similarity = 1 - a.dot(b.T) / norm1.dot(norm2.T)
    
    ## by default outputs 2 x 2 matrix
    if out_dim == 0:
        return similarity[0,0]
    elif out_dim == 1:
        return similarity[:,0]

    return similarity
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation that would work for matrices as well. Its behaviour is exactly like sklearn cosine similarity:

```
def cosine_similarity(a, b):    
    return np.divide(
        np.dot(a, b.T),
        np.linalg.norm(
            a,
            axis=1,
            keepdims=True
        ) 
        @ # matrix multiplication
        np.linalg.norm(
            b,
            axis=1,
            keepdims=True
        ).T
    )
```

The @ symbol stands for matrix multiplication. See
[What does the "at" (@) symbol do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python/28997112#28997112)

Answer (score -3):

All the answers are great for situations where you cannot use NumPy. If you can, here is another approach:

```
def cosine(x, y):
    dot_products = np.dot(x, y.T)
    norm_products = np.linalg.norm(x) * np.linalg.norm(y)
    return dot_products / (norm_products + EPSILON)
```

Also bear in mind about `EPSILON = 1e-07` to secure the division.