# How to run a large matrix for cosine similarity in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate cosine similarity between articles. And I am running into the problem that my implementation approach would take a long time for the size of the data that I am going to run.

```
from scipy import spatial
import numpy as np 
from numpy import array
import sklearn
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity 

I = [[3, 45, 7, 2],[2, 54, 13, 15], [2, 54, 1, 13]]

II = [2, 54, 13, 15]

print cosine_similarity(II, I)
```

With the example above, to calculate I and II already took 1.0s and the dimension of my data is around (100K, 2K).

Is there other packages that I could use to run a huge matrix?

Comment: several examples are here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424228/cosine-similarity-between-2-number-lists

Comment: @minitoto the top answer is exactly the implementation I have. But I think it doesn't solve the problem of the big size data.

Answer (score 2):

With `sklearn.preprocessing.normalize`, this works faster for me

```
result = np.dot(normalize(II, axis=1), normalize(I, axis=1).T)
```

(dot product between unit-normalized vectors is equivalent to cosine similarity).

Answer (score 2):

You can use pairwise_kernels with metric='cosine' and n_jobs = . That will divide the data and run it in parallel

Comment: Unfortunately unlike the cosine_similarity method, this doesn't support sparse output.