# Cosine similarity between query and document in a search engine

Tags: nlp, ranking, information-retrieval, cosine-similarity, ranking-functions

I am going through the Manning book for Information retrieval. Currently I am at the part about cosine similarity. One thing is not clear for me.
 Lets say I have the tf-idf vectors for the query and a document. I want  to compute the cosine similarity between both vectors. When I compute the magnitude for the document vector do I sum the squares of all the terms in the vector or just the terms in the query?

Here is an example : we have user query "cat food beef" .
Lets say its vector is (0,1,0,1,1).( assume there are only 5 directions in the vector one for each unique word in the query and the document)
We have a document "Beef is delicious"
Its vector is (1,1,1,0,0). We want to find the cosine similarity between the query and the document vectors.

Comment: Cross-site duplicates: [on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/311983/183808), [on Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/24370/323)

Answer (score 1):

Cosine similarity is simply a fraction where

- the numerator is the dot product between 2 vectors
- the denominator is product of the magnitude of the 2 vectors

  - i.e. euclidean length, i.e. the square root of the dot product of the vector with itself

for the numerator, e.g. in `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> x = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
>>> np.dot(x,y)
1.0
```

Similarly if we compute the dot product by multiply x_i and y_i and summing the individual elements:

```
>>> x_dot_y = sum([(1.0 * 0.0) + (1.0 * 1.0) + (1.0 * 0.0) + (0.0 * 1.0) + (0.0 * 1.0)])
>>> x_dot_y
1.0
```

For the denominator, we can compute the magnitude in `numpy`:

```
>>> from numpy.linalg import norm
>>> y = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
>>> x = [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
>>> norm(x) * norm(y)
2.9999999999999996
```

Similarly, if we compute the euclidean length without numpy

```
>>> import math
# with np.dot
>>> math.sqrt(np.dot(x,x)) * math.sqrt(np.dot(y,y))
2.9999999999999996
```

So the cosine similarity is:

```
>>> cos_x_y = np.dot(x,y) / (norm(x) * norm(y))
>>> cos_x_y
0.33333333333333337
```

You can also use the cosine distance function directly from `scipy`:

```
>>> from scipy import spatial
>>> 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(x,y)
0.33333333333333337
```

See also

- [How to calculate cosine similarity given 2 sentence strings? - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173225/how-to-calculate-cosine-similarity-given-2-sentence-strings-python)
- [Cosine Similarity between 2 Number Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424228/cosine-similarity-between-2-number-lists)