# How can I keep index and column names when performing sklearn cosine similarity?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cosine-similarity

When performing sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity, the results I got came with index 0, 1, 2... and column names 0, 1, 2...

How can I turn the results to be with original column and index names?

Dataframe for calculation:

```
    user_id  |    age      |  education   |   income    | length_residence
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    NIODB6S3 |  43.769912  |  1.537634    |  58.754647  |     7.232344
    BOAWG65L |  43.769912  |  1.537634    |  58.754647  |     7.232344
    3667B8P0 |  20.000000  |  1.000000    |  40.000000  |     4.000000
    VS53SKY5 |  35.000000  |  1.537634    |  75.000000  |    14.000000
```

Code I ran:

```
    pd.DataFrame(cosine_similarity(df))
```

Expected:

```
    user_id  |  NIODB6S3  | BOAWG65L  | 3667B8P0
    user_id  |
    ----------------------------------------------
    NIODB6S3 |  1.000000  | 0.000084  | 0.996848
    BOAWG65L |  0.000084  | 1.000000  | 0.000342
    3667B8P0 |  0.996848  | 0.000342  | 1.000000
```

Got:

```
      |     0     |    1      |     2
    --------------------------------------
    0 | 1.000000  | 0.000084  | 0.996848
    1 | 0.000084  | 1.000000  | 0.000342
    2 | 0.996848  | 0.000342  | 1.000000
```

I'm not sure if the default numeric index conveys the **correct and original order of 'user_id' in df**.

Answer (score 1):

Checked with [Cosine Similarity between 2 Number Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424228/cosine-similarity-between-2-number-lists)

```
scipy.spatial.distance.cosine(array1, array2)
```

I can replace index and columns in the results with original index

```
result.index = df.index
result.columns = df.index
```

They are exactly in the same order