# How to find the cosine similarity between a vector that is generated from an edge list of graph nodes in python?

Tags: python-3.x, vector, data-mining, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate the cosine similarity score for some graph nodes from a given vector embedding file. How do I calculate the score now for each node in python?
I believe using the scikit-learn, we can solve this.

I have generated an edge list from a series of graph nodes. Then I converted the edge list into a vector graph embedding using node2vec.

I expect the output to show the cosine similarity score for each node

```
   1 -> 0.2
   2 -> 0.4
   3 -> 0.5
   .
   .
```

I am sorry if I was not able to explain my problem properly because I am new to data science. I can clarify in the comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cosine Similarity between 2 Number Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424228/cosine-similarity-between-2-number-lists)

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz But Sir this only takes a number list into consideration and finds the cosine similarity between the two. I want to find the cosine similarity for each of the graph nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The function `cosine_similarity` accepts a data matrix as input.

It then returns a matrix of pairwise similarities.

Comment: But  does it show the cosine similarity value for each pair?

Comment: It does not "show" anything. It returns a matrix. If you want to  print a particular format, write code to print that format. You example above does not make sense, as cosine similarities are between two nodes, not one.