# Compute all cosine similarities in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, vectorization, cosine-similarity

Say I have a matrix `mat` an `100 x 200` array.

My question is twofold:

1. How can I compute the cosine similarity of the first row against all the other rows? I tried using `sklearn`'s `cosine_similarity` function but passing in a `100 x 200` matrix gives me a `100 x 100` array (instead of a `100 x 1` array).
2. If I wanted to compute the cosine similarities of all the rows against the others, say compute all 100 C 2 = 4950 different combinations of all the rows, would it be fastest **not** to use something like `sklearn` but actually store the norms of each of the rows by `np.linalg.norm` and then compute each similarity by [`cos_sim = dot(a, b)/(norm(a)*norm(b))`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424228/cosine-similarity-between-2-number-lists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- try:

```py
cosines = (numpy.inner(mat[0], mat) / (numpy.linalg.norm(mat[0]) * numpy.linalg.norm(mat, axis=1)))
```

2- you can check the previous code to do similar thing knowing that

```py
numpy.linalg.norm(mat, axis=1)
```

computing the norms of all vectors and then you multiply by the current one for each step.
also

```py
numpy.inner(mat, mat)
```

will give you a symmetric matrix of the matrix inner product.