# return Cosine Similarity not as single value

Tags: python, numpy

How can I make a pure NumPy function that will return an array of the shape of the 2 arrays with the cosine similarities of all the pairwise comparisons of the rows of the input array?

I don't want to return a single value.

```
dataSet1 = [5, 6, 7, 2]
dataSet2 = [2, 3, 1, 15]

def cosine_similarity(list1, list2):
  # How to?
  pass

print(cosine_similarity(dataSet1, dataSet2))
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy` for this as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424228/cosine-similarity-between-2-number-lists).

```
from scipy import spatial

dataSet1 = [5, 6, 7, 2]
dataSet2 = [2, 3, 1, 15]
result = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(dataSet1, dataSet2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the cosine_similarity function from sklearn.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer ##if the documents are text
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
def cos(docs):
    if len(docs)==1:
        return []

    cos_final = []
    count_vectorizer= CountVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize)
    doc1= ['missing' if x is np.nan else x for x in docs]
    count_vec=count_vectorizer.fit_transform(doc1)
    #print(count_vec)
    cosine_sim_matrix= cosine_similarity(count_vec)

    

    #print(cosine_sim_matrix)
    return cosine_sim_matrix
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is [cosine_similarity from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html) library.

Here is a simple example:

Lets we have `x` which has 5 dimensional 3 vectors and `y` which has only 1 vector. We can compute cosine similarity as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

x = np.random.rand(3,5)
y = np.random.rand(1,5)

# >>> x
# array([[0.21668023, 0.05705532, 0.6391782 , 0.97990692, 0.90601101],
#        [0.82725409, 0.30221347, 0.98101159, 0.13982621, 0.88490538],
#        [0.09895812, 0.19948788, 0.12710054, 0.61409403, 0.56001643]])
# >>> y
# array([[0.70531146, 0.10222257, 0.6027328 , 0.87662291, 0.27053804]])

cosine_similarity(x, y)
```

Then the output is the cosine similarity of each vector from `x` (3) with `y` (1) so the output has `3x1` values:

```
array([[0.84139047],
       [0.75146312],
       [0.75255157]])
```