# Cosine Simiarlity scores for each array combination in a list of arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pairwise

I have list of arrays and I want to calculate the cosine similarity for each combination of arrays in my list of arrays.

My full list comprises 20 arrays with 3 x 25000. A small selection below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity,cosine_distances


C = np.array([[-127, -108, -290],
       [-123,  -83, -333],
       [-126,  -69, -354],
       [-146, -211, -241],
       [-151, -209, -253],
       [-157, -200, -254]])



D = np.array([[-129, -146, -231],
       [-127, -148, -238],
       [-132, -157, -231],
       [ -93, -355, -112],
       [ -95, -325, -137],
       [ -99, -282, -163]])



E = np.array(([[-141, -133, -200],
       [-132, -123, -202],
       [-119, -117, -204],
       [-107, -210, -228],
       [-101, -194, -243],
       [-105, -175, -244]]))


ArrayList = (C,D,E)
```

My first problem is I am getting a pairwise result for each element of each array, however, what I am trying to achieve is the result looking at the arrays as a whole.

For example I try

```
scores = cosine_similarity(C,D)
scores
array([[0.98078461, 0.98258287, 0.97458466, 0.643815  , 0.71118811,
        0.7929595 ],
       [0.95226207, 0.95528395, 0.9428837 , 0.55905221, 0.63291722,
        0.7240552 ],
       [0.9363733 , 0.93972303, 0.9255921 , 0.51752531, 0.59402196,
        0.68918496],
       [0.98998438, 0.98903931, 0.99377116, 0.85494921, 0.8979725 ,
        0.9449272 ],
       [0.99335622, 0.99255262, 0.99635952, 0.84106771, 0.88619755,
        0.93616556],
       [0.9955969 , 0.99463213, 0.99794805, 0.82706302, 0.8738389 ,
        0.92640196]])
```

What I am expecting is a singular value 0.989... (this is a made up number)
The next challenge is how to iterate over each array in my list of arrays to get a pairwise result of the array something like this

```
     C    D       E
C  1.0    0.97   0.95
 
D  0.97   1.0    0.96

E  0.95  0.95    1.0
```

As a beginner to python I am not sure how to proceed. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cosine Similarity between 2 Number Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18424228/cosine-similarity-between-2-number-lists)

Comment: @Ali_Sh thanks for the link, its close but from what I could see it did not address my question letting me compare multiple arrays stored in a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do is to get he cosine distance when using each matrix as an `1Xn` dimensional vector. The easiest thing in my opinion will be to vectorially implement the cosine similarity with numpy functions. As a reminder, given two 1D vectors `x` and `y`, the cosine similarity is given by:

```
cosine_similarity = x.dot(y) / (np.linalg.norm(x, 2) * np.linalg.norm(y, 2))
```

To do this with the three metrices, we will first flatten them into 1D representation and stack them together:

```
matrices_1d = temp = np.vstack((C.reshape((1, -1)), D.reshape(1, -1), E.reshape(1,-1)))
```

Now that we have the vector-representation of each matrix, we can compute the L2 norm using `np.linalg.norm`([read on this functions here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)) as follows:

```
norm_vec = np.linalg.norm(matrices_1d , ord=2, axis=1)
```

And finally, we can compute the cosine distances as follows:

```
cos_sim = matrices_1d .dot(matrices_1d .T) / np.outer(norm_vec ,norm_vec)
# array([[1.        , 0.9126993 , 0.9699609 ],
#        [0.9126993 , 1.        , 0.93485159],
#        [0.9699609 , 0.93485159, 1.        ]])
```

Note that as a sanity check, the diagonal values are 1 since the cosine distance of a vector from itself is 1.

The cosine distance if defined to be `1-cos_sim` and is easy to computeonce you have the similarity.