# Difference between scipy, numpy, sklearn, torch module when used to calculate cosine_similarity?

Tags: python

The spatial.cosine.distance() function from the scipy module calculates the distance instead of the cosine similarity, but to achieve that, we can subtract the value of the distance from 1.

```py
from scipy import spatial
List1 = [4, 47, 8, 3]
List2 = [3, 52, 12, 16]
result = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(List1, List2)
print(result)
```

The numpy.dot() function calculates the dot product of the two vectors passed as parameters. The numpy.norm() function returns the vector norm.

I can use these functions with the correct formula to calculate the cosine similarity.

```py
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm
List1 = [4, 47, 8, 3]
List2 = [3, 52, 12, 16]
result = dot(List1, List2)/(norm(List1)*norm(List2))
print(result)
```

In the sklearn module, there is an in-built function called cosine_similarity() to calculate the cosine similarity.

```py
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity,cosine_distances
A=np.array([10,3])
B=np.array([8,7])
result=cosine_similarity(A.reshape(1,-1),B.reshape(1,-1))
print(result)
```

When I deal with N-dimensional tensors having shapes (m,n), I can use the consine_similarity() function from the torch module to find the cosine similarity.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
t1 = [3,45,6,8]
a = torch.FloatTensor(t1)

t2 = [4,54,3,7]
b = torch.FloatTensor(t2)
result = F.cosine_similarity(a, b, dim=0)

print(result)
```

Which method should I use to get the best similarity results if I use 2d array using the above modules in python?

Comment: They do the same. There could be a numerical difference, but I did not notice any.  The speed is a bit different. The numpy is the fastest for me of these 4, but the manual implementation may be even faster (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18424953/3219777) in many cases. sklearn is significantly slower than others.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento Thanks! Because I not really understand it when I using above modules, this confuses me when choosing a solution to my problem.

Comment: But I input 2d array it not working "(stackoverflow.com/a/18424953/3219777)" 
```python a = ([1,2,3,4],[4,3,2,1]) b = ([3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7])```  I expect result ```python [0.8 0.7 0.5 0.4]```

Comment: @AskoldIlvento they work the same for 1D x 2D or 1D x 1D but beyond that the torch cosine similarity is not the same. For instance:

`x = np.random.rand(10, 10)
y = np.random.rand(10, 10)
torch_cos = torch.nn.functional.cosine_similarity(torch.tensor(x), torch.tensor(y)).numpy()
sklearn_cos = sklearn_cosine_similarity(x, y)

assert (torch_cos == sklearn).all()`

They will not even be the same shape.  To make them the same shape you will need to add a dim to a tensor but then they are not the same computation.

Comment: To expand, the diagonal on the sklearn matrix will be the same as the values from torch with the simple inputs but if you want an N X N cosine similarity output you will need to unsqueeze and transpose in some order.