# What is the @ doing in the following code?

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to start using Pyglet to start creating some GUI interfaces with Python, using what I've learned so far.  I'm no expert, in fact I probably know just enough to be dangerous.  In looking at the documentation I understand everything so far except ....

Mouse events are handled in a similar way:

```
from pyglet.window import mouse

@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if button == mouse.LEFT:
        print 'The left mouse button was pressed.'
```

What exactly is the @window.event doing  specifically the @.  I've written event handlers before, so I understand that concept, but I'm at a loss.  Based on some searching, both here and on google, I think it is some type of decorator, but I'm just not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Jason

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/101447#101447

Comment: Decorator Basics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python/1594484#1594484

Comment: And also [What does the @ symbol do in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-python)

Comment: @paisanco: that's the duplicate I was looking for :)