# Function/variable legal syntax

Tags: python

I understand the idea that we follow our own naming convention, but is this totally so? For instance a function/variable name cannot begin with a number but can include 'special' characters, right? However this:

```
@methodtrace(utils.logger)
```

raises questions for me. Are the `@` and `.` significant? I have read [What is the naming convention in Python for variable and function names?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159720/3001761)

Comment: You can follow your own convention ([PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) preferred), but can still only use [valid Python identifiers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). `@` is used (from 2.4) for function decorators and (from 3.5) matrix multiplication, and `.` is for attribute access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "at" (@) symbol do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

This is not a matter of coding *style* (which for Python is defined in [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), but of *syntax*. What you have posted **is not a single name**. It means:

```
@methodtrace(utils.logger)
```

```
^ decorate the following function
 ^ with the result of calling the function methodtrace
             ^ with a single argument, the logger attribute of utils
```

A valid Python identifier is defined in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) - it must start with a letter (upper- or lower-case) and then include zero or more letters or numbers. The `@` is syntactical sugar for decorating a function (see [What does the "at" (@) symbol do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python)), the parentheses are syntax for calling a function/method and the `.` is used for access to the attributes of an object.