# What does `@pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak.NoNewlines` mean?

Tags: python

I stumbled upon the following piece of code [here](https://losfuzzys.github.io/writeup/2016/12/18/sharifctf7-guess-persian-nomoreblind/):

```
@pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak.NoNewlines
def fmtleak(addr):
    ...
    return res

printf_leaked = fmtleak.q(printf_got)
...
```

Can anybody please explain what `@pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak.NoNewlines` (on the beginning line) and `fmtleak.q` mean in this context? What sort of Python syntax are used, and what are they?

Comment: `@pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak.NoNewlines` is a decorator. and I'm pretty sure `fmtleak.q` is a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to [*pwntools* -- `pwnlib`](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/3.0.1/about.html).

I'm going to explain about what you're talking about. However I'm assuming that you know what [*Call stack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) is, and [exploitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)) techniques such as *Information leakage* and [*Uncontrolled format string* also known as *Format string bug*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string); so you need to learn what you don't know among them to understand what I'm going to say.

---

### [*DynELF*](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/3.0.1/dynelf.html)

The writer of [the article you mentioned](https://losfuzzys.github.io/writeup/2016/12/18/sharifctf7-guess-persian-nomoreblind/) was trying to use [*DynELF*](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/3.0.1/dynelf.html), one of the features provided by *pwntools* that resolves remote functions using leaks.
[*DynELF*](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/3.0.1/dynelf.html) requires a Python function or a `pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak` object that leaks data at a given address as much as possible.

> #### `class pwnlib.dynelf.DynELF(leak, pointer=None, elf=None)`
>
> *DynELF* knows how to resolve symbols in remote processes via an infoleak(information leakage) or memleak(memory leakage) vulnerability encapsulated by `pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak`.

---

### *Decorator*

First of all,

```
@pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak.NoNewlines
def fmtleak(addr):
    ...
    return res

printf_leaked = fmtleak.q(printf_got)
```

is equivalent to

```
def fmtleak(addr):
    ...
    return res
fmtleak = pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak.NoNewlines(fmtleak)
printf_leaked = fmtleak.q(printf_got)
```

; the `@` is Python syntax for [decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python)s.

So the `fmtleak` becomes an instance of `MemLeak` class, returned by the `NoNewlines` method.

---

### `NoNewlines`

`pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak.NoNewlines`, which is a static method of `pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak` class, creates a `pwnlib.memleak.MemLeak` object, with a *leak function*(function to leak data) wrapped with a wrapper function that ignores leakage request for memory addresses whose memory representations contain a byte for a newline character, 0x0A('\n').
The reason why this is needed is because there are cases such as: leaking data at an address by using an *uncontrolled format string* from a function such as `fgets`, which stops to read when it reads a newline, which can lead to unintended data resulting when the address has a newline byte.

From the `man` page for the `fgets` function:

> `fgets()` reads in at most one less than `size` characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by `s`. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.

From [`pwnlib/memleak.py`](https://pypkg.com/pypi/pwntools/f/pwnlib/memleak.py):

```
@staticmethod
def NoNewlines(function):
    """Wrapper for leak functions such that addresses which contain newline
    bytes are not leaked.

    This is useful if the address which is used for the leak is provided by
    e.g. ``fgets()``.
    """

    @functools.wraps(function, updated=[])
    def whitespace_wrapper(address, *a, **kw):
        if '\n' in pack(address):
            log.info('Ignoring leak request for %#x: Contains newlines' % address)
            return None
        return function(address, *a, **kw)

    return MemLeak(whitespace_wrapper)
```

---

### `MemLeak` class's `q` method

`q` method, which is of `MemLeak` class, tries to leak 64 bits of value at a given memory address with the *leak function* provided. If it cannot leak it completely, returns `None`.

From [`pwnlib/memleak.py`](https://pypkg.com/pypi/pwntools/f/pwnlib/memleak.py):

```
def q(self, addr, ndx = 0):
    """q(addr, ndx = 0) -> int

    Leak qword at ``((uint64_t*) addr)[ndx]``

    Examples:

        >>> import string
        >>> data = string.ascii_lowercase
        >>> l = MemLeak(lambda a: data[a:a+16], reraise=False)
        >>> l.q(0) == unpack('abcdefgh', 64)
        True
        >>> l.q(18) == unpack('stuvwxyz', 64)
        True
        >>> l.q(19) is None
        True
    """
    return self._b(addr, ndx, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python the symbol @ is used for a decorator.

```
@dec1
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
```

which is equivalent to the following piece of code:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec1(func)
```

And as per your question `.q` is not a keyword in python syntax but it must be a function in your code.

Answer (score 0):

## @ in Python is the sign for a Decorator

A decorator dynamically alter the functionality of a function, method, or class without having to directly use subclasses or change the source code of the function being decorated. In general it is a design pattern that allows behavior to be added to an individual object, either statically or dynamically, without affecting the behavior of other objects from the same class.
In Python decorators are simply wrappers to existing functions. Here is a guide to it: http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/