# What does the @ mean in this equation?

Tags: numpy, cosine-similarity, trigonometry

I am seeing this equation for computing the cosine similarity of a vector and a matrix in a post.

```
The numerator of cos similarity can be expressed as a matrix multiply and then the denominator should just work :).

    a_norm = np.linalg.norm(a, axis=1)
    b_norm = np.linalg.norm(b)
    (a @ b) / (a_norm * b_norm)
    where a is a 2D array and b is 1D array (i.e. vector)
```

What does the (a @ b) mean? How to compute this in numpy?

Comment: Use `numpy.matmul`.

Comment: Particularly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46027116/2285236) answer.

Comment: Did you read the comment you pasted? hint: "The numerator of cos similarity can be expressed as a **matrix multiply** ..."