# Python: word between at sign (@)

Tags: python, python-3.x, meson-build

In [this](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/blob/master/piper.in) script from one of the linux applications I use, I see words between the "@" sign such as `@devel@`, and `@gtk_major_version@`.
I would like to know what those are called, their functions in Python, and why the script has ".in" extension instead of ".py".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the "at" (@) symbol do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python)

Comment: In this case, I don't think that '@' is used to make a decorator.

Instead, it seems that the file is a template and @VARIABLE@ is made as reference to a variable defined elsewhere.

Comment: This is not valid Python code. It is somehow preprocessed. The preprocessor uses these @...@ syntax.

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading the source code correctly, but it seems like the variables are defined [here](https://github.com/libratbag/piper/blob/d45b95b4339cd9ae2fd17dff5d0244e994189e51/meson.build). Seems to be related to the Meson Build System.

Comment: @KostasCharitidis no that's at sign in the begining of the word, this is at sign surrounding a word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is not Python syntax.  Instead, the strings enclosed in `@` are template variables that will be filled in by the [Meson build system](https://mesonbuild.com/Configuration.html) which is popular, e.g. with many projects that use GTK.

I this case the template will be used at build time to generate a script called just `piper` (with the `.in` removed) similarly to how autoconf generates files from templates, with the template variables replaced with values determined by the build system.

Using a build configure system to generate a Python script is slightly unusual but not at all unheard of either.  I'm sure I've done the same before, albeit with autoconf.