# What's the usage of '@' in python?

Tags: python, syntax

I've seen in several places, but I still don't know what is the usage of '@' in python.

For example here:

```py
class C:
    @staticmethod
    def f(arg1, arg2, ...): ...
```

Could someone make this all thing clear for me?

Comment: Did you even briefly research this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python, for example.

Answer (score 0):

@ is for decorators.
A decorator is the name used for a software design pattern. Decorators dynamically alter the functionality of a function, method, or class without having to directly use subclasses or change the source code of the function being decorated.