# What does the "@" operator do in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to understand some code in which I found this statement. I don't know what **"@"** sign is doing here.

This is a running code for landmark detection, you can check full code here: https://github.com/cleardusk/3DDFA/blob/master/utils/ddfa.py

```
vertex = p @ (u + w_shp @ alpha_shp + w_exp @ alpha_exp).reshape(3, -1, order='F') + offset
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's used for matrix multiplication. Refer this for more: [What does the "at" (@) symbol do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python)

Comment: Vote to close as duplicate, don't add an "answer" that's just a link to another question.

Comment: For a metaphor on how to think about it, see the classic [meta] post [Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer); a sign telling someone where to get apples is not an apple, just as a link telling someone where to find an answer is not an answer itself.

Comment: it is not the same problem i think

Comment: @ParagJain, there's more than one possibility given in that link; read all of them (specifically including the discussion of matrix multiplication), not just the first one.

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow so I'll keep that in mind next time.

Comment: @charles okay!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184344/14122 is a specific answer on the linked question that focuses *only* on matrix multiplication.

Comment: thanks man you want me to delete this question