# What is meaning of '@' operator?

Tags: python, pca

I have come across this code and I have seen this unusual operation:

```
return Xtrain @ eigenvectors[:2]
```

Does anyone know what it does?

Comment: TL;DR - matrix multiplication

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "at" (@) symbol do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python) Note, that your case is *not* in the accepted answer, but in one of the others. It is an overloaded operator.

Answer (score 1):

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) says:

> #### Matrix Multiplication
>
> **Operator**
>
> ```
> a @ b
> ```
>
> **Function**
>
> ```
> matmul(a, b)
> ```