# What is the Meaning Of '@' before A function In Python 3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I searched for the meaning of `@` when it comes before a function in Python and I couldn't find a helpful thing.

For example, I saw this code in Django:

```
@login_required
```

...and this in the goto-statement package:

```
@with_goto
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Have a search for ‘**python decorators**’.  And please can you rewrite your question using proper case; it’s difficult to read.  Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python

Comment: It is decorator syntax. It is syntactic sugar for `def foo(): ....; foo = decorator(foo)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It represent the `Decorator`. A decorator is a function that takes another function and extends the behavior of the latter function without explicitly modifying it.

```
def decorator_function(func):
    def inner_function():
        print("Before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("After the function is called.")
    return inner_function

@decorator_function
def args_funtion():
    print("In the middle we are!")
```

Actually this `@decorator_function` decorator perform the same job as:

```
args_funtion = decorator_function(args_funtion)
```

And now if you call it this would be the result:

```
>>> args_funtion()
Before the function is called.
In the middle we are!
After the function is called.
```