# What is @ in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This may sound stupid but what's @ in Python like I see this:

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
```

and I don't understand what is does lol

(sorry for a dumb question)

Comment: It's a "decorator". Googling this term should help you.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python

Comment: @kwkt don't be quick to just declare it a decorator. It has more than one purpose in python

Comment: @MZ At least in the context he gave, that's a decorator. I also know it's matrix multiplication in numeric computation modules, but what else is it?

Comment: This question has been answered numerous times before. Unfortunately, in accordance with Stack Overflow's quality standards, we don't accept duplicate questions. Please use the search function or your search engine of choice to research *before* posting here.