# What does @ mean in python programming language?

Tags: python

The code is:

```
def init_network(vocab_size, n_embedding):

    model = {
    "w1": np.random.randn(vocab_size, n_embedding),
    "w2": np.random.randn(n_embedding, vocab_size)
    }
    return model
```

model = init_network(len(word_to_idex), 10)

X @ model["w1"]

In what case do we need to use? Please, give me An example if it is possible.

Comment: [What does the "at" (@) symbol do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28997112)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute a program or call a system command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command-from-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "at" (@) symbol do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

It's shorthand for matrix multiplication in `numpy`:

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html