# Use of @ on dataframe pyhton?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

So I tried to study about `TOPSIS`.
Here is the [reference](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hungrybluedev/topsis-implementation/notebook). In the first normalizing step, there is code like this:

```
divisors[j] = np.sqrt(column @ column)
```

I tried to look the meaning of `@`, but I still couldn't find it. Based on the formula, at the divisor, we need to square the `xij` first, then sum, then do the square root. At code, when do the column values be summed together?

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6392739, `@` is used for matrix multiplication here.

Comment: @Ch3steR if it's matrix multiplication, matrix column is matrix with size 1x5, so it should be multiplied by matrix with size 5x1

Comment: For numpy arrays, it's the operator form of `np.matmul`.  For 2d arrays this is the same as `np.dot`

Comment: judging from its name, `column` is a vector right? in that case, `@` is the same as the inner product of two vectors.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to compute:

`np.sqrt(np.dot(column, column))`

This will first square each element of `column`, then sum the squared elements, then take the square root of the sum. It will work if `column` is an array with shape `(n,)` or `(n,1)` or `(1,n)`.

As has already been pointed out in the comments, `@` is for matrix multiplication. So if `column` has shape `(n, 1)`, then `np.sqrt(column.T @ column)` will achieve the same result.