# Python: why does x @ y.T not produce the same output as np.outer(x,y)?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, outer-product

In python, if `x,y` are vectors, I expected `x @ y.T` to give me the outer product of x and y, i.e. to match the result of `np.outer(x,y)`.  However, to my surprise, `x @ y.T` returns a scalar.  Why?  Are vectors (i.e. one-dimensional arrays) not considered to be column vectors by numpy?

For example, the code

```
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1,2])
y=np.array([3,4])

wrong_answer = x @ y.T 
right_answer = np.outer(x,y)
```

gives the (interactive) output

```
In [1]: wrong_answer
Out[1]: 11

In [2]: right_answer
Out[2]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

Comment: No, 1d arrays are not column vectors.  If anything they are closer to row vectors (by the rules of broadcasting).  But if you take time to read `np.transpose`, you'll learn that it does not change a 1d array into a 2d one.  @ is documented at `np.matmul`.  Read it.

Comment: `@` is basically a dot product of the two arrays, while `*` is element-wise multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` takes the dot product, not the outer product.

Using the variables you defined in the code:

```
>>> x=np.array([1,2])
>>> y=np.array([3,4])
>>> np.dot(x,y)
11
```

You get 11, which is the dot product that was produced using '@'

EDIT: update from discussion

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python/28997112#28997112) as well as digging through the [PEP465](https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/), the `@` operator uses `__matmul__` under the hood, which is also taking the dot product.

```
>>> x.__matmul__(y)
11
```

Comment: Re: "The @ takes the dot product, not the outer product.": I find this behavior of Python to be very strange, as I have been interpreting `@` to be the matrix multiplication operator.   I believe this interpretation is common?  E.g. a quick search of the internet yielded:  "PEP 465 introduced the @ infix operator that is designated to be used for matrix multiplication."

Comment: Yep, that's correct! PEP 465 did introduce that, but under the hood it's using the `__matmul__` method, which is actually taking the dot product. If you ran `x.__matmul__(y)`, you'll get the same dot product, since that's what the `@` operator is using under the hood. I'll update my answer to reflect that

Comment: `np.matmul(x,y)`

Answer (score 0):

"*Are vectors (i.e. one-dimensional arrays) not considered to be column vectors by numpy?*" -> No, you would need to add a dimension. And `@` is a dot product, not a multiplication.

You need:

```
x[:,None]*y
```

Output:

```
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

You can check that transposing a 1D array doesn't change anything:

```
y.T
array([3, 4])
```

Comment: Re: " No, you would need to add a dimension.":  Interesting.  If I do `xx=x[:,np.newaxis]` and `yy=y[:,np.newaxis]` then now `np.dim(xx)=np.ndim(yy)=2` and `xx @ yy.T` gives the intended result.   But having to call `np.newaxis` all the time strikes me as annoying boilerplate.  Is there something I'm missing?   Is there some reason why `y` is not considered a column vector (with `y.T` giving the transpose, i.e. creating an array with shape (2,1))?

Comment: In which language were you able to do this? There are no row/columns vectors, only n-dimensional arrays in numpy (a column vector would be a (k,1) 2D array). And why using the dot product?

Answer (score 0):

`np.transpose`, `np.dot` and `np.matmul` all document their behavior when given 1d arrays.  `broadcasting` is also a good thing to understand.

Your two arrays are both 1d:

```
In [250]: x=np.array([1,2])
     ...: y=np.array([3,4])    
In [251]: x.shape
Out[251]: (2,)
```

`transpose` does not change the dimensions of a 1d array; it does not add a dimension.  It just reorders existing dimensions:

```
In [252]: y.T.shape
Out[252]: (2,)
```

`outer` explicitly says it works with 1d arrays (and ravels others):

```
In [254]: np.outer(x,y)
Out[254]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

As a long term `numpy` user, I prefer to use the broadcasted multiply:

```
In [255]: x[:,None]*y        # (n,1)*(m) => (n,1)*(1,m) => (n,m)   
Out[255]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

`outer` also likens its action to `np.einsum`, but I'll skip that for now.

`dot/matmul` explicitly says what it does with 1d arrays:

```
In [256]: np.dot(x,y)            # dot of 1d arrays is inner product
Out[256]: 11

In [257]: np.matmul(x,y)         # x@y
Out[257]: 11
```

`broadcasting` doesn't work with `@/matmul` (for the last 2 dimensions, that is):

```
In [260]: x[:,None]@y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [260], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 x[:,None]@y

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 1)
```

But (n,1) with (1,m) => (n,m), with the shared size 1 dimension as the sum-of-products dimension:

```
In [261]: x[:,None]@y[None,:]
Out[261]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

In this case using the broadcasted multiply does the same thing:

```
In [262]: x[:,None]*y[None,:]   # "column vector" * "row vector"
Out[262]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

Another way to control dimension is to use `np.einsum`:

```
In [263]: np.einsum('i,i',x,y)
Out[263]: 11

In [264]: np.einsum('i,j',x,y)
Out[264]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [6, 8]])

In [265]: np.einsum('i,i->i',x,y)       # x*y
Out[265]: array([3, 8])
```

Because 1d arrays are really that,  not row/column vectors in disguise, we may need to add a dimension here or there to match behavior that we are used seeing with matrix-oriented languages like MATLAB.