# Could anybody explain me the workflow of the decorator and how this example works?

Tags: python

```
def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper



@log
def run(a, b, c):
    print(a+b+c)
    
run(1,5,c=9)
```

The function 'run' has three arguments and we run the function at the bottom. The function has decorator and I am trying to understand how the decorator works in this case.

what does it contain the argument 'func' in the log.
How does it work the 'wrapper' and where does it know the arguments.
How does it work
`val = func(*args, **kwargs)`

I understand the process about 70% but I still don't feel sure enough so i hope someone can take some time to explain the process.

Comment: 1. It's the function you're wrapping. 2. It gets passed them. 3. What do you mean? Read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/739654/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6392739/3001761.

Comment: "what does it contain the argument 'func' in the log." Because that's what a decorator is. It is a function (callable) that takes another function (callable) as an argument and (usually) returns a function (callable) as a result

Comment: Read [this extensive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/5014455) in the linked duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorators are used using `@` syntax. For example,

```
@log
def a_fun(a, b, c):
   ...
```

This calls, same as (that is, equivalent to but more handier than):

```
a_fun = log(a_fun)
```

From below:

```
def log(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        val = func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper



@log
def run(a, b, c):
    print(a+b+c)
    
run(1,5,c=9)
```

To start with :

```
def log(func):
```

This is defining a function, `log`. It take a single argument, `func`. Here it is equal to a callable (a function).

Note from above, we had:

```
... = log(a_fun)
```

Hence, it can be clearly understood that the value of `func`, in this specific example, is equal to `a_fun` exactly (passed in value).

Next, we go to :

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
```

This is declaring a function, of name `wrapper`. It takes generic parameters, that is `*args, **kwargs` which is familiar ppython syntax, when you don't necessarily know which arguments or keywords that a function is going to accept. Thus, it is defined as such in order to be as generic and inclusive as possible, so as to apply to any kind of function (taking zero to hundred+ arguments, and same with keyword arguments for example).

Note that type of `*args` is a `tuple[Any...]` meaning it is a tuple of one of more elements (of any type). Type of `**kwargs` is a `dict[str, Any]`, meaning it is a `dict` containing parameter name as key (`str` obviously, as we cannot define a func like `def my_fun(123: int)` for instance) and value as any type (since it is not known here).

This can be confirm with:

```py
assert type(args) is tuple
assert type(kwargs) is dict
```

Finally:

```
val = func(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is saying, pass or forward the captured input `*args` and `**kwargs`, and unpack and pass them as-is to the callable or function `func`.

Then `val` here is the return value of the function `func` - if it does not return anything, this will be `None`, else it will be the returned value of the function itself.

As mentioned from above, the value of `func` in this context is exactly equal to `run`. Thusly, the value of `*args` is equal to the evaluated value of `(a, b, c)` and the value of `**kwargs` depends on how the function is invoked - for example, `run(..., 0, c=2)` would result in the `kwargs` object being populated in this specific use case as `dict(c=2)` as that is how the function or callable is being invoked. Conversely, the `args` object in this case would then be a tuple `(..., 0)` as those are the specific *positional* arguments (separate from named or keyword arguments, which are captured into `kwargs` as mentioned above).

Note that in this example, `run` does not return anything:

```py
def run(a, b, c):
    print(a+b+c)
```

More specifically, it returns `None`, as `print(...)` always returns `None`.

Hence,

```
val = ...
```

from the above, the value of `val` will thus be captured as `None`.

```
assert val is None
```

This can be used to confirm (or disprove) the above point.

Lastly but not leastly, we cannot forget the `return` statement that also comes into play here:

```
return wrapper
```

This is saying, from the decorator function `log`, I want to return a new function `wrapper`. So that, the meaning is, the original (or decorated) function will have its value overwritten.

So to clarify, remember from above the following syntax:

```
@log
def a_fun(a, b, c):
   ...
```

That as mentioned, this is then equivalent to:

```
a_fun = log(a_fun)
```

So the value `log(a_fun)`, is whatever the return value of the decorator function `log` is.

In this specific case, as mentioned the return value of `log` is `wrapper`, as the return statement does indicate that as well.

Thus, the evaluated value of the original (decorated) function `a_fun` would then be:

```
a_fun = wrapper
```

Hence, we have prove that the original or un-decorated function `a_fun` (the underlying callable that is) now have its value overwritten by the decorator, and that its new assigned value is thus `wrapper`. So we have an equivalency here of `a_fun == wrapper` after the decorator `@log` is applied.

Hope that is helpful, or at least clarifies it rather than obfuscates the problem statement and what is happening exactly in the code. At least, the goal here is to not muddy the waters, but rather to provide clarity through openness and the sharing of information such not necessarily that understanding is achieved, but that at the least we thus end up at a better place and situation than where we initially started or originated from.