# I came across this function in a course i'm taking. what is this part W@X doing?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, loss-function, minimization

I came across this function in a course i'm taking. what is this part W@X doing?

```
def my_loss(w):
    s = 0
    for i in range(0, 569):
        raw_model_output = w@X[i]
        s = s + log_loss(raw_model_output * y[i])
    return s

# Returns the w that makes my_loss(w) smallest
w_fit = minimize(my_loss, X[0]).x
print(w_fit)

# Compare with scikit-learn's LogisticRegression
lr = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=False, C=1000000).fit(X,y)
print(lr.coef_)
```

It's an implementation of sklearn's Logistic Regression in Python

Comment: https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/

Comment: Duplicate [What does the "at" (@) symbol do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392739/what-does-the-at-symbol-do-in-python)

Comment: The w@X[i] code is performing a matrix multiplication between two arrays/tensors w and X[i].

Comment: Got it. Thank you